# How can I set the world_scale and x\y difference values to get a close match between physics body and display object?

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d, scaling, starling-framework

I'm using this [Flash Box2D engine](http://www.box2dflash.org/) in a Starling App, but I couldn't understand how to match Box2D world scale/center axis with Starling screen. Example:

```
//I created a bodyDef here:
bodyDef = new b2BodyDef();
//x\y_pos is the position on the screen where I want the body to stay
bodyDef.position.Set(x_difference + x_pos/world_scale, y_difference + y_pos/world_scale)

//Same for size...
//I created a shape here:
boxShape = new b2PolygonShape();
boxShape.SetAsBox(x_size/world_scale, y_size/world_scale);
```

How can I set the `world_scale` and `x\y_difference` values to get a close match between the body and the starling display object?

Searching  on google, I saw `world_scale = 30`, but why and how can I set the position reference difference `x\y_difference`?

Comment: the scale is entirely up to you, typically 30 means one meter in Box2D world equals 30 points or pixels on the screen. You just figure out what works best for you as there's no standardized conversion between (virtual) metric units and pixels / ppi / dpi

Comment: That's what I wanted to know, put as answer. About `x\y_difference`, testing, I saw They are zero.